# Is there an R function for descriptive statistics if a defined substring is contained in a specific column of the dataframe?

Tags: r

```r
df <- data.frame(X = c("ABCD", "CDEF", "ADF"), Y = c(4, 9, 6))
```

Very simplified, my dataframe looks as above. In this example I would like create descriptive statistics for Y (mean, median, sd at minimum) if X contains a specific letter.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

---

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want statistics when X contains for example A? So, mean, median, etc... when A is included regardless of the rest of the letters? What do you want for the rows with no A? Remove them?

Comment: Do you want statistics when X contains for example A? YES So, mean, median, etc... when A is included regardless of the rest of the letters? YES What do you want for the rows with no A? Remove them? THE Y'S FOR DATASETS THAT DO NOT CONTAIN A ARE NOT CONSIDERED FOR DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS

Answer (score 4):

If your dataframe is `d`, and looks as below, you can use `dplyr`/`stringr` like this, noting below that I'm using "W" as stand in for "a specific letter":

```
d %>% 
  filter(str_detect(X,"W")) %>% 
  summarize(across(Y,list("mean" = mean,"median" = median,"sd" =sd)))
```

Ouput:

```
  Y_mean Y_median    Y_sd
1   9.25       10 3.40343
```

Of course, in base R, you can very simply use `grepl` like this `d[grepl("W",d$X),"Y"]` to get the same vector of Y values, and you could then get various descriptive information, using `summary()`, or `sd()`, etc, etc

Input:

```
set.seed(12345)
d = tibble(
  X = sapply(1:20, \(x) paste0(sample(LETTERS,4), collapse="")),
  Y = ceiling(runif(1:20,3,15))
)

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   X         Y
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 NSPK     14
 2 XBVK      7
 3 FGJQ      6
 4 HGFA     11
 5 LTHZ      8
 6 CINM     13
 7 TJWP      8
 8 PBTI     13
 9 YDHK     14
10 FIEO     15
11 SQYE     11
12 ZJCS      4
13 MCQJ      7
14 XKZT     10
15 BLCM     10
16 VSWJ      5
17 WZGO     12
18 ENWL     12
19 ZXCE     13
20 KDZQ     15
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response - i tried both options without success

Comment: 1) Error: 'Summarize' does not work with matrices.

Comment: 2) (grepl option) Error in x[j] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: how can these be resolved? your input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: your question is closed. You need to provide a better reproducible example, because the code above does work on the example you provide.  Try my solutions on the input data. If you input data does not have a similar structure, then, you need to show an example of your input data.